# Who take care tcp message order

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I listen to tcp socket  in linux with `recv` or `recvfrom`.

Who taking care that I will get the tcp packets on the right order?

Is that the kernel taking care so if packet 1 came after packet 2 the kernel will drop out both/save packet 2 until packet 1 will come?

Or maybe I need to take care on user-space to the order of tcp packet?

Comment: When using TCP, you will receive the data in the same order it was sent.

Comment: Userspace *can't even see* packet boundaries with TCP. It's purely a data stream.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux based systems in any normal scenario, this is handled by the kernel.

You can find the [source code here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e595dd94515ed6bc5ba38fce0f9598db8c0ee9a9/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L4790), and here's an abridged version:

```
/*  Queue data for delivery to the user.
 *  Packets in sequence go to the receive queue.
 *  Out of sequence packets to the out_of_order_queue.
 */
if (TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->seq == tp->rcv_nxt) {
   /* packet is in order */
}

if (!after(TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->end_seq, tp->rcv_nxt)) {
   /* already received */
} 

if (!before(TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->seq, tp->rcv_nxt + tcp_receive_window(tp)))
    goto out_of_window;

if (before(TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->seq, tp->rcv_nxt)) {
    /* Partial packet, seq < rcv_next < end_seq */
}

/* append to out-of-order queue */
tcp_data_queue_ofo(sk, skb);
```

along with the [actual implementation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e595dd94515ed6bc5ba38fce0f9598db8c0ee9a9/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L4555) that does the reordering using RB trees:

Answer (score 1):

To quote Wikipedia,

> At the lower levels of the protocol stack, due to network congestion, traffic load balancing, or unpredictable network behaviour, IP packets may be lost, duplicated, or delivered out of order. **TCP detects these problems, requests re-transmission of lost data, rearranges out-of-order data**, [...]

It's an inherent property of the protocol that you will receive the data in the correct order (or not at all).

Note that TCP is a stream protocol, so you can't even detect packet boundaries. A call to `recv`/`recvfrom` may return a portion of a packet, and it may return bytes that came from more than one packet.